# DOM updated , however changes not visible in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-chosen

I'm trying to populate html select with an ajax call using jquery. I can see that the dom is getting updated with data from database , however the updated options are not visible on brower.

Here is the static html:

```
<td>
    <div>
      <select data-placeholder="-Role-" multiple class="chosen-select"
                                        style="width:170px;">
       <option value="TEST_ROLE1">TEST_ROLE1</option>
       <option value="TEST_ROLE2">TEST_ROLE2</option>
      </select>
      <span userId="grouproleError" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-4"
                                        style="display:none"></span>
    </div>
</td>
```

Following is the script code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.chosen-select').chosen({}).change(function (obj, result) {
                console.debug("changed: %o", arguments);
                console.log("selected: " + result.selected);
            });
            /**
             * Get All roles
             **/
            console.log('Getting all roles..' + new Date().toLocaleString());
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8081/admin/roles/getallroles",
                context: document.body,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    var list = $(".chosen-select");
                    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        list.append(new Option(item.rolesShortName, item.rolesShortName));
                    });
                    console.log('Roles fetched:' + JSON.stringify(data));
                },
                error: function () {
                    window.location.replace("http://localhost:8081");
                }
            });

            $('form').submit(function (event) {
                register(event);
            });
        });

        $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
            $(".log").text("Triggered ajaxStop handler.");
        });
}
```

You can see that the static options are the only options getting displayed.
Options retrieved from the database are updated in the DOM however they are not getting displayed. What do you think I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Go here: https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ And find `Updating Chosen Dynamically`. In short, you need to do: `$('.chosen-select').trigger('chosen:updated')` after you modify the DOM.

Comment: @Adam. I'm embarrassed. Checked the document and added
 $(".chosen-select").trigger("chosen:updated"); at the end of ajax call and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#change-update-events) `$('.chosen-select').trigger('chosen:updated')` was required after the DOM was modified.